Как выполнить статическую линковку с использованием libzip для создания исполняемого файла без DLL?
Есть проект C++ который использует библиотеку libzip, и после компиляции создаются несколько dll файлов без которых программа не работает, подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать статичискую линовку для этой библиотеки
